# Override a method in the third party

Tags: c#

I have a third party party class say `Log`. It contains the methods

```
public void Write(string s, params object[] args)
{
            Monitor.Enter(this);
            try
            {
                            string logEntry = string.Format(s, args);
                            this.Write(logEntry);
            }
            finally
            {
                            Monitor.Exit(this);
            }
}
```

And

```
public void Write(string LogEntry)
{
    this.Write(0, LogEntry);
}
```

I defined a property `outLog` in my own class

```
public static Log OutLog  {get;set;}
```

I want to use the feature "CallerMemberNameAttribute" etc. in .net 4.5 and override the `Write` method as something like:

```
public void Write(string s,
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(this);
        try
        {
            string logEntry = string.Format(s, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
            this.Write(logEntry);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(this);
        }
    }
```

So I can call it in my class:

```
outLog.Write(...);
```

Not sure how?

Comment: It's non-virtual, so you can't override it. If you can live with just having an additional method, you should replace `this.Write` with `base.Write` in your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't override it, but you can create an extension method (which is signified by the `this` keyword on its first parameter) that will do what you want. Something like:

```
public static class LogExtensions
{
    public static void WriteWithCallerInfo(
        this Log log,
        string s,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(log);
        try
        {
            string logEntry = string.Format(s, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
            log.Write(logEntry);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(log);
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can then write:

```
OutLog.WriteWithCallerInfo("whatever");
```

The extension method can't be called just `Write`, because normal methods take precedence over extension methods.

Note that I also don't understand the reason for the locking, I think it shouldn't be necessary, assuming the overload `Write(int, string)` is thread-safe.

Comment: -@svick, <code>OutLog</code> is the field, do I have to pass it in the extension method? I saw that you call <code>OutLog.WriteWithCallerInfo("whatever");</code>. Why it is not <code>LogExtensions.WriteWithCallerInfo("whatever");</code>

Comment: @Love That's what extension methods are: you can call them as `object.Method(other_parameters)` and it behaves the same as if you write `StaticClassName.Method(object, other_parameters)`. Try it.

Comment: If you write an extension method that looks like an instance method, it will never be used. If you give it another name, it can be an instance method. However, I would go with an also go with an extension method in this case.

Comment: “If you give it another name, it can be an instance method.” Not if you don't control the original type, which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot override non virtual/abstract members.

You can [hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/435f1dw2.aspx) but that will only work as long as you use the instance as being an instance of your class. If you use it as being an instance of the base class, it will call the base classe's method.

Comment: It is a comment rather than an answer. Code please.

Comment: What code? What didn't you understand? Did you read the article?